# How does ScalaTest check equality?

Tags: scala, equality, scalatest

I reference [this](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingEqualityWithMatchers).

I'm new to ScalaTest, but I interpret that as meaning that, if I've implemented `==`, then that will be used to interpret `should equal`. However, my code appears to contradict that.

I'm working through [Odersky's book](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) - I'm on exercise 6.0.3. I've implemented the Natural numbers as above, with the addition of equality operators:

```
class Succ(x: Nat) extends Nat {
  ...
  override def ==(that:Nat): Boolean = {
    try {
      (that - this).isZero
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable => false
    }
  }
}

object Zero extends Nat {
  ...
  override def ==(that:Nat): Boolean = {
    that.isZero
  }
}
```

However, the following test case fails:

```
def makeNat(n:Integer):Nat = {
  if (n < 0) throw new RuntimeException("Can't generate Nat from <0: " + n.toString())
  if (n==0) return Zero
  else return makeNat(n-1).suc
}

test("Addition is commutative") {

   val nats = for (n <- Gen.choose(0, 1000)) yield  makeNat(n)
   val p = forAll ((nats, "n1"), (nats, "n2")) {
      (n1: Nat, n2: Nat) =>
        (n1 + n2) should equal (n2 + n1) //Fails
    }

}
```

But subtracting the arguments and comparing with Zero passes:

```
test("Addition is commutative") {

  val nats = for (n <- Gen.choose(0, 1000)) yield  makeNat(n)

  val p = forAll ((nats, "n1"), (nats, "n2")) {
    (n1: Nat, n2: Nat) =>
      ((n1 + n2)-(n2+n1)) should equal (Zero) // Passes
  }

}
```

---

EDIT: thanks to dwickern@, this was solved - I needed to add overrides for the `equals` methods, not the `==` methods. I.e.:

```
  override def equals(that:Any): Boolean = that match {
    case that:Nat => (that-this).isZero
    case _ => false
  }
```

Comment: What `==` are you overriding? Scala's `==` method calls the standard Java `Object.equals`. It's `equals` that you should override.

Comment: I had only overriden ==, but (as edited in above) I've now overriden .equals as well, and I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Ignore that - I think I ran the tests before saving. Tests pass now! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out, you need to override `equals` instead of `==`. The `==` method in scala calls Java's standard `Object.equals` except it handles null properly without throwing exceptions.

In practice you don't need to override `equals` very often because case classes exist. To use them, change your `class` to `case class` and your `object` to `case object`. The compiler will implement `equals` and `hashCode` for you. Case classes are a good fit if a class follows these patterns:

- The class is treated like a value. (definitely true for a natural number class!)
- The case class should be immutable. Equality and mutability don't mix.
- Avoid class inheritance. Equality + inheritance is complicated. Use traits instead.